# Ubuntu Uninstall . What partitions I should delete?

Tags: uninstall

Ok, so here is a screenshot of my partitions in GParted:

[image]

And I just want Windows 8 but NO MORE Ubuntu at ALL.

I can see a partition that contains linux_swap but how do I delete the sda4 then? (It looks like it is protected :( )

And I should FIRST repair the Boot Loader?

And how do I set Windows 8.1 to boot by default in the Windows Bootloader?

(I only have Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu installed, I am currently using the "Try Ubuntu" option from the LiveCD, but I do have it installed on my PC as a Dual-Boot.)

I installed Ubuntu without WUBI and I do not have UEFI since I did update to Windows 8 then 8.1 and I had Windows 7 with my PC.

I just want to know what partitions to delete and if I should first repair bootloader.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use this link on [Disk Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) to know more about disk partitions... And that's a good link above, which I repost here: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 1):

- Boot ubuntu-live disk and then install gparted.
- Open gparted,and make sure that you doesn't had mounted any sda partitions.
- Delete `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6` partitions.
- Atlast ran [*boot-repair*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: I am already on the LiveCD. I have GParted and /dev/sda6 has a little key icon?

Comment: right click on the sda6 and unmount it by selecting swap off option.

Comment: Do I delete de sda4 too?

Comment: no,it is an extended partition.There you store any number of logical partitions.

Comment: But I can do it if I feel like it right?

Comment: its your wish to delete it or not.

Answer (score 0):

as told here, boot with a live distro (or gparted-live), remove and format NTFS /dev/sda5, /dev/sda6 and /dev/sda4, then reboot with Windows setup dvd. 
You can start a dos-commandline shell from there (try googling to see exactly which is the way: I remember something like "troubleshoot", then "advanced") and in dos-shell execute

bootrec /fixmbr

then reboot from HDU.

Cheers,

Silvia